# Converting string to datetime with whitespace data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert the dates in a csv from strings to datetime objects. The csv is in the format

```
date quantity
2010-01-01 10:10:10.276455   100
```

and the code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('python test.txt',delim_whitespace=True,parse_dates=['date'])

df.info()
```

I get the error "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a `'\t'` separator (not `delim_whitespace`), which would keep the date together but separate the two fields?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your CSV headers to the following:

```
date       time              quantity
2010-01-01 10:10:10.276455   100
```

Then, read in the file under the assumption that it has 3 columns:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('python test.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Finally, generate the timestamp column you want using string concatenation and `pd.to_datetime`:

```py
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: Hello @MrFuppes I have corrected my answer.  I did not know this.  The problem with the OP's CSV file is that the time timestamp is not in double quotes or some other delimiter.  Therefore, we don't know whether space means delimiter or part of the timestamp.  My answer is one approach; there may be others as well.

Comment: maybe instead of modifying the input, e.g. read with `delimiter=r"\s{2,}"` (split on two or more occurrences of whitespace) could be a better option here. But I'm also just guessing the "real" format of the OP's input ;-)

Comment: `My answer is one approach; there may be others as well.`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to split on multiple whitespaces (*not* a single space for example), another approach might be to set the delimiter to `r"\s{2,}"`, Ex:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """date   value
2010-01-01 10:10:10.276455   100
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delimiter=r"\s{2,}")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# df.info()
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
# Data columns (total 2 columns):
#  #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
# ---  ------  --------------  -----         
#  0   date    1 non-null      datetime64[ns]
#  1   value   1 non-null      int64         
# dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
# memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```